# Value Object and business logic evolution

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

While playing with DDD and Value Objects particularly, I have some problems.

VOs hide validation logic in constructors\fabric methods, allowing us to count on the fact that the object is always in a consistent state. So, no explicit validation is needed in all places where we work with, say, phone number that could have been represented by string instead.

So, no object will be constructed from wrong input data. Or we could create a special "invalid" VO. But I see this as a step backwards because we will be forced to check its validity each time we work with this.

> My question is what should we do when our business logic is changing,
>   but data stored in database is not. All time we was able to accept any
>   combination of numbers, hypens and brackets from user input as valid
>   phone number. But at some time validation logic has been changed to be
>   more strict: valid phone number should only begin with +1, narrowing
>   to USA numbers.

We could not raise exception when creating VO PhoneNumber from this kind of data from DB as it disallow UI from being filled with data that user could fix. Also, we could not create VO from invalid data, because this will remove benefit of always being in consistent state and bring us back to point were we were check input data all the time we work with it.

What approach could be used to allow us using VOs and still be able to read invalid (valid by old rules, which were gone) data? May be some kind of versioning of VOs? When new business logic arrive we not change old VO, but create (inherit) new one? Or something else? Whatever it is, I believe it should not discard ability of VO to always be consistent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We could not raise exception when creating VO PhoneNumber from this kind of data from DB as it disallow UI from being filled with data that user could fix. Also, we could not create VO from invalid data, because this will remove benefit of always being in consistent state and bring us back to point were we were check input data all the time we work with it.

Sounds like you are not using CQRS otherwise this wouldn't be an issue in the first place.

In CQRS you would split your commands (and data models too) into queries and commands, where commands mutate the data (=operate on the aggregate) whereas queries operate on the read model (projection of your aggregate data).

For queries you don't need validation, its a mere form of projected data (i.e. so you can query it or have fast read access w/o it being blocked from mutating operations of the commands).

If applying CQRS correctly with two separate models (read and write models), reading "invalid" data is still possible. But any changes to this data must obey the new business rules.

Comment: That sounds very reasonable. Existing data may be read "as is" into simple POCO, but changes should go through all validation logic.

Thanks a lot.